# Counter not incrementing for radio button in android

Tags: java, android

am using an if statement to increment the answer for a quiz app in android. i think for loop or while loop should work berrter. But i hae also tested that . am now getting it well.

Below is my code. Thank you

```
package newton.quizapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.CursorJoiner;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
private RadioGroup radioGroup2;
private RadioGroup radioGroup3;
private RadioButton radioButton1;
private RadioButton radioButton2;
private RadioButton radioButton3;
private Button btnSubmit;
private int Ans = 0;


private TextView Total;
```

// private int wrong  = 0;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    String All;
     Total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Score);


    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg3);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId1 = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId1);

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId2 = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId3 = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId3);


                if (radioButton1.getText().equals("Hyper Text Markup Language")) {

                    Ans++;

                }

                    else  if (radioButton2.getText().equals("The World Wide Web Consortium")) {
                        // Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Incorrect Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Ans++;

                    }
                   else if (radioButton2.getText().equals("Specific places within a particular page")) {

                       Ans++;

                    }


                    Total.setText("You Got " + Ans + " Answer correct out of 3");


            Ans =0;
        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior and what's the wrong behavior you are observing?

Comment: So, what exactly is "*not increment*" and under what conditions?

Comment: i want the Total.setText to set answer out of 3
It only show You got 1 Answer correct out of 3 even if you choose all correct answer.. @Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your conditions to :

```
if (radioButton1.getText().equals("Hyper Text Markup Language")) {
    Ans++;
}
if (radioButton2.getText().equals("The World Wide Web Consortium")) {
    // Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Incorrect Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Ans++;
}
if (radioButton3.getText().equals("Specific places within a particular page")) {
    Ans++;
}
```

In your original code of `if (...) ... else if (...) ... else if (...) ...`, only one condition can be met (since the first time a condition evaluates to true, no other conditions would be checked), so Ans can only be 0 or 1.

In addition, I'm assuming your last if should check `radioButon3`.

Comment: I have tried that before. Its like its taken just the first radio button and did not goto the next one.. and thank you for correcting the the 3rd radio button.. but it not still working yet

Comment: @Softwarex3 It would take only the first radio button if `radioButton1.getText().equals("Hyper Text Markup Language")` and you have the `if ... else if ... else if ...` code. If you use distinct if conditions, it should work (unless you have a problem elsewhere in your code).

Comment: I dont know too. Thank you anyway for your time. Wil keep trying